# Call function from different file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to keep my files as clean and reusable as possible so when I request my data in the `componentDidMount()` function I want to call a function that returns data from a different file.

At the moment I have this:

```
import NewsService from './news/service/news.service.js';
componentDidMount(){
  NewsService.logData;
}
```

And the other file:

```
const Test = {
  logData: getData()
}

function getData(){
  console.log('test')
  data = [];
  return data
};

export default Test;
```

But that's not working. In fact, it logs `test` on load, which is understandable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you're defining the value of the attribute `logData` by running the function. What you need to do is pass a reference to the `getData` function, and then call it at will.

```
const Test = {
  logData: getData
}

// or

const Test = {
  logData: (props) => getData(props)
}


function getData(props){
  console.log('test', props)
  data = [];
  return data
};
```

And then..

```
componentDidMount(){
  NewsService.logData({foo: 'bar'});
}
```

This is assuming that you are wanting to get data during componentDidMount, not  just when the app loads and then store it in the `logData` attribute.

**Update**: Modified example to include passing params. Notice that in the first example, you don't have to specify props because the function reference itself is being passed, so you just add the props when firing. But, in the second example, you have to specify the props (because you're basically creating a new function that will return `getData`). So you have to pass the props down into it.

Comment: Great! glad to help.

Comment: Just an off topic question, if I would like to pass a parameter, can I do it like this: `NewsService.logData(input);` and in the other file: `logData: () => getData(input)` ?

Comment: Thanks again, helped me alot!

Comment: Wasn't it simply missing the function call? `NewsService.logData;` becomes `NewsService.logData();`

Comment: @FMC, yes and no. Yes, it needed to call a function instead of pointing to it. But, the `logData` wasn't actually a function because it was calling `getData` when it loaded, instead of pointing to `getData`.

Comment: @BradBumbalough My bad, I misread. I think I got confused as the data was already set in `getData`, but it would be set once and for all. Your example allows for true reusability.

Comment: @FMC no worries! I thought the same way at first too.